# Advanced Custom Fields and Google Maps Multiple Markers

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have some code that generates a Google Map to show a marker based on the location field supplied via a custom field named 'event_map'. It works great.

```
<?php 
$location = get_field('event_map');
if( !empty($location) ):
?>
<div class="acf-map">
<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I now want to add a map that shows ALL of the markers from ALL of the posts from the 'tour-dates' custom post type. How would I go about doing this assuming all of these posts have a field called 'event_map' to draw location data from? I am stumped and any help appreciated.

Comment: Have used/tried using any of the available plugins for Google Maps from Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

Get the posts with such post type and loop on it then use the ACF API `get_field` (the second parameter let us define the post ID in which your custom field value belongs to).

```
<?php 
$tours = get_posts( array(
   'post_type' => 'tour-dates', 
   'posts_per_page' => -1
));

if( !empty($tours) ): ?>


<div class="acf-map">

  <?php foreach($tours as $tour): ?>
    <?php
     $location = get_field('event_map',$tour->ID);

     if( !empty($location) ): ?>

     <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>

    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?> 

</div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should get all `tour-dates` posts that have information in the `event_map` field.

```
$new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'tour-dates',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_map',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
) );
```

I'm not sure what you're using to display the map, so I can't help beyond that.